# Why do the arresting gear cables need to be pushed/ guided back?

Tags: military, jet, aircraft-carrier, us-navy, arresting-gear

Also, what is the yellow metal stick officially called?

[image: The cross-deck pendant (arresting wire) on the USS John C. Stennis is retracted below deck by the purchase cable and arresting engine, but to ensure it sweeps smoothly across the flight deck, it’s guided by U.S. Navy Seaman Willtavius Ward and Seaman Wyatt Steen.]

Comment: Do you have a source for the image? That may even be good start to finding an answer.

Comment: That’s done principally to make sure that the cross deck pendant does not get snagged on anything during the retraction process or pose a hazard to personnel nearby.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely, it is to avoid this kind of situation:

> Retraction sometimes causes formation of long, loose helical loops in the deck pendant. Such loops are usually eliminated as tension increases on the pendant. Occasionally a loop, instead of being eliminated, tightens into a small loop called a kink. Kinks can also form if the retraction cycle is halted abruptly; if the retraction is not a smooth, continuous operation; or if the torque is allowed to build up in the cable.

Additionally, the cable must be visually checked every time is used (if time allows it).

I have no idea about the name of the stick :)

Source: https://www.navair.navy.mil/sites/g/files/jejdrs536/files/2018-11/14353A_ch9.pdf